# Can I make our breakpoint in my code editor in c#

Tags: c#, breakpoints

I am making our ide in c# WinForms then I think can I make a  breakpoint in our ide for debugging code like Java and other 
.i want to add breakpoint in our ide

Comment: I don't understand your question. What IDE are you talking about? Are you saying you are writing your own IDE for Java?

Comment: Totally unclear.

Comment: If you simply mean to set a breakpoint in your C# code, then click on the gray border to the left of your code. This adds a brown dot - the breakpoint. [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio / Set a breakpoint and start the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019#set-a-breakpoint-and-start-the-debugger)

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Visual Studio, the F9 key will toggle a breakpoint on the current line.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is not a question. It is a feature that must be implemented.

Many years ago our team implemented a similar program for a custom scripting language by C#.
You must do some GUI things and using an interpreter to do the command and stop it when reach the line that specified by breakpoints.

You can use SharpCode.TextEditor or DigitalRune.Windows.TextEditor or .... They have some features to show the user the running line and breakpoints and also they have code completion and other useful features.