# C# in Visual Studios: How to print to console during a break point

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I do not normally code in C# and was wondering if Visual Studio had a particular debugging feature that is similar to the Python Debugger. In the PDB, during a breakpoint I will often print certain function calls and variables as well as test certain if statements. Although I can see variables in the 'locals' tab, I can't do print statements like list[i] or foo(var) or if(f(x) == 1) which I think are powerful debugging tools. Is this feature at all available in VS? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028025/can-i-make-our-breakpoint-in-my-code-editor-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: No I know how to add a breakpoint, I don't know how to print to console after that - I've seen people put Debug.Write as part of the code, but that's as good as putting a print() statement in python to debug and for a code which takes minutes to run, this is not ideal as I have to come up with new print statements and then recompile etc

Comment: Right-click the breakpoint, Actions. You can add statements to print there, and they will be written to the Output window. You can also set conditions.

Comment: Quick Watch, or just hover over the variable?

Comment: There is also the Immediate window that can be used to run arbitrary code and display the result. There are some limitations on what code can be run, but it works with most normal things.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, you can "Insert Tracepoint" from the context menu under "Breakpoint". Alternatively, you can create a breakpoint and open its properties then set the "Actions" checkbox.

[image: inserting tracepoint]

Comment: Thank you for your response, so after I set the action that I want say Console.Write('Hello World'), and also untoggle 'Continue code execution' if I press continue, I will still be at the same exact line as the breakpoint, correct?

Comment: In that case, you'd put `"Hello World"` inside the "Show a message in the Output Window" box. If you untoggle "Continue code execution", then the debugger will break when it hits the breakpoint, and remain broken; if it is toggled, the debugger will stop, print the message you specify, then immediately resume execution

Comment: @canton7 so basically, back to the original question is there a way to Break, print and stay at the same line then print again? So break, print, print, ...,  print, continue?